# JS prototype and inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

In my spare time I try to learn a little bit of JS, but I stuck with the topic in subject.

```js
var person = new Person("Bob", "Smith", 52);
var teacher = new Teacher("Adam", "Greff", 209);

function Humans(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
}

function Person(firstName, lastName, age) {
  Humans.call(this, firstName, lastName);
  this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype = Object.create(Humans.prototype);

Person.prototype.fullDetail = function() {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " " + this.age;
};


function Teacher(firstName, lastName, roomNumber) {
  Humans.call(this, firstName, lastName);
  this.room = roomNumber;
}

Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Humans.prototype);

Teacher.prototype.fullDetail = function() {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " " + this.room;
};

person.fullDetail();
```

Can anybody tell me why I cant execute `person.fullDetail();`?

If you could make some comments with your version of code, I would be very grateful, thanks.

Comment: you are creating the instances before defining the functions!

Comment: @DanielA.White Hoisting fixes some of this

Comment: Hoisting only applies to a few of the functions here.

Comment: @Feathercrown Not the issue of setting the wrong prototype, which is exactly the problem

Comment: @Bergi yeah, on second thought, it doesn't fix the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody, this is by far the hardest subject I came across in JS, but with this example and with your help its much clearer now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're creating your objects before you've defined what their prototypes should be.

When you do

```
var person = new Person ("Bob", "Smith", 52);
```

you're making an object based on the *current* definition of `Person`. Later in that code, you're changing the prototype of `Person` in it's entirety

```
Person.prototype = Object.create(Humans.prototype);
```

To fix this, create your objects *after* you're done re-assigning the prototype.

```js
function Humans(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
}

function Person(firstName, lastName, age) {
  Humans.call(this, firstName, lastName);
  this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype = Object.create(Humans.prototype);

Person.prototype.fullDetail = function() {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " " + this.age;
};


function Teacher(firstName, lastName, roomNumber) {
  Humans.call(this, firstName, lastName);
  this.room = roomNumber;
}

Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Humans.prototype);

Teacher.prototype.fullDetail = function() {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " " + this.room;
};

var person = new Person("Bob", "Smith", 52);
var teacher = new Teacher("Adam", "Greff", 209);
console.log(person.fullDetail());
```

Comment: You can actually prove it by showing that `Object.getPrototypeOf(person)` !== `Person.prototype`. The prototype or the original is person instance is "lost" and replaced. Very interesting edge case for javascript inheritance!

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is because when you are creating person object Person prototype has no FullDetail method.

Change the ordering of your object creation ,create person object after adding methods to prototype

check this snippet

```js
var teacher;
var person;
function Humans(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
}

function Person(firstName, lastName, age) {
  Humans.call(this, firstName, lastName);
  this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype = Object.create(Humans.prototype);

Person.prototype.fullDetail = function() {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " " + this.age;
};

 person = new Person("Bob", "Smith", 52);

function Teacher(firstName, lastName, roomNumber) {
  Humans.call(this, firstName, lastName);
  this.room = roomNumber;
}

Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Humans.prototype);

Teacher.prototype.fullDetail = function() {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " " + this.room;
};
teacher= new Teacher("Adam", "Greff", 209);
console.log(person.fullDetail());
console.log(teacher.fullDetail());
```

Hope it helps

Comment: While this fixes that use case, it doesn't fix the fact that `teacher` is still broken!

Comment: Just to add, the reason you're able to *create* a person before the constructor function (and prototype changes) is because of this annoying/counter-intuitive thing called 'hoisting' https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting.

Comment: @tcooc try moving the `teacher` instantiation down below the `Teacher` constructor

Comment: Your explanation isn't entirely correct. It does not matter when the methods are added to the prototype - it just needs to be done before calling them.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you create the person and teacher without having their functions defined yet in the prototype. Try this:

```js
    function Humans(firstName, lastName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    
    function Person(firstName, lastName, age) {
      Humans.call(this, firstName, lastName);
      this.age = age;
    }
    
    Person.prototype = Object.create(Humans.prototype);
    
    Person.prototype.fullDetail = function() {
      return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " " + this.age; 
    };
    
    
    function Teacher(firstName, lastName, roomNumber) {
      Humans.call(this, firstName, lastName);
      this.room = roomNumber;
    }
    
    Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Humans.prototype);
    
    Teacher.prototype.fullDetail = function() {
      return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " " + this.room; 
    };
    var person = new Person ("Bob", "Smith", 52);
    var teacher = new Teacher ("Adam", "Greff", 209);
    
    console.log(person.fullDetail());
```

```html
( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are at ES6, you could use the new class syntax like

```
class ExampleBaseClass {
    // Do things here...
}

class ExampleClass extends ExampleBaseClass {
    // Do other things here...
    // You may use methods from ExampleBaseClass here.
}
```

See: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-ecmascript-6-class-inheritance/